# Error when attempting to register user

Tags: php

so i'm in the process of coding the register form for my website. I've got all the necessary files written up, however when I enter all the correct details into the registration form, the page just refreshes as opposed to redirecting to register-success.php. Any help

Here are all my codes as regards to the register process:

```
<?php

require_once('functions.inc');

//Prevent access if they haven't submitted the form.
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    die(header("Location: register.php"));
}

$_SESSION['formAttempt'] = true;

if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
     }
     
    $_SESSION['error'] = array();
   
    $required = array("username", "email", "password1", "password2");
   
    //Check required fields
    foreach ($required as $requiredField) {
            if (!isset($_POST[$requiredField]) || $_POST[$requiredField] == "" ) {
                    $_SESSION['error'][]= $requiredField."is required.";
            }
    }
   
    if (!preg_match('/^[\w.]+$/',$_POST['username'])){
            $_SESSON['error'][] = "Username must contain onyl letters and numbers.";
    }
   
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = "Invalid email address";
    }
   
    if($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2']) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = "Passwords do not match.";
    }
   
    //Final disposition
    if(count($_SESSION['error']) > 0) {
            die(header("Location: register.php"));
    } else {
            if(registerUser($_POST)) {
                    unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
                    die(header("Location: register-success.php"));
            } else {
                    error_log("Problem registering user: {$_POST['email']}");
                    $_SESSION['error'][] = "Problem registering account";
                    die(header("Location:register.php"));
            }
    }
   
    function registerUser($userData) {
            $mysqli = new mysqli (DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DB);
            if ($mysqli->conntect_errno) {
                    error_log("Cannot connect to MYSQL: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
                    return false;
            }
            $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
           
            //check for an existing user
            $findUser = "SELECT id from users where email = '{$email}'";
            $findResult = $mysqli->query($findUser);
            $findRow = $findResult->fetch_assoc();
            if(isset($findRow['id']) && $findRow['id'] != "") {
                    $_SESSION['error'][] = "A user with the email provided already exists.";
                    return false;
            }
           
            $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
           
            $cryptedPassword = crypt($_POST['password1']);
            $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($cryptedPassword);
           
            $query = "INSERT INTO users ( create_date, email, password, username) ".
            "VALUES ('NOW(), '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$username}'";
            if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
                    $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                    error_log("Inserted {$email} as ID {$id}");
                    return true;
            } else {
                    error_log("Problem inserting {$query}");
                    return false;
            }
    } //end function registerUser
```

?>

I'm getting this error in my logs:

> [17-Feb-2015 00:03:20 Europe/Berlin] Problem inserting INSERT INTO users ( create_date, email, password, username) VALUES (NOW(), '123@123.com', '$1$Xo..U65.$A8zl/2CaTGSs0ZvRPe6wy1', '1'
>
> [17-Feb-2015 00:03:20 Europe/Berlin] Problem registering user: 123@123.com

Comment: Please read our [help]

Comment: @PeeHaa, added code above...

Comment: Just turn error reporting using error_reporting(E_ALL);, and then try to localize error. If you are still stuck, update your question with relevant data.

Comment: Also check your session. There is no session_start() visible in your code, and if that part is missing session will not work.

Comment: @Whirlwind Where would session_start() normally go in the files?

Comment: session_start() should go at the top of the page before any output...

Comment: @Whirlwind I get that, but what file? registration-process or another?

Comment: You need to call session_start(); on each and every page if you are planning to use session variables there.

Comment: You should update your question with errors. It's more readable, because comments are not suitable for this.

Comment: @Whirlwind Sorry, I am new to SF. Edited question.

Comment: That error is result probably of error_log function and it's pointing you at the part of the code where you register your user. Try to debug your registerUser() function. use var_dump() to check all variables, check/print your query etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your registerUser method:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (`create_date`, `email`, `password`, `username`) VALUES (NOW(), '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$username}')";
```

Comment: still getting the same error, as well as something about a salt parameter

Comment: Have you included error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of your page? Also add ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: Yup, I've included those at the top of the php tag and I am still getting the same error message